# Visual studio ".exe" built application cannot open in other computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've build a visual studio 2015 project into  ".exe" and it worked on my computer and other computer. And then after i update my visual studio 2015, and build the program again, the ".exe" won't open on other computer, but it working as usual on my computer.

1. Does it have anything to do with the update ?
2. I've tried it on 3 others computers, on windows 7 it shows error clr20r3. But on windows 10 it doesnt show the error message

**UPDATE :** Sorry for not being specific. After googling i have found many similliar problem and it have something to do with the Net Framework. I've check my project application project target Net Framework it is 4.5.2. And i already create a setup wizard for it and it's include Net Framework 4.5.2 offline installer. I build it everything fine, then i try to run the Net Framework 4.5.2 installer on other computer, it says Net Framework 4.5.2 already updated/installed. But my app still wont open on that computer, only a loading (circle) symbol, but then the app won't open.

Comment: what error it was showing?

Comment: Is the correct .NET Framework (including all available updates for it) installed on the PC were the application is not working / not starting?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information we cannot guarantee we'll provide a correct answer.

You should check for:

- .NET Framework (in which you built the project with)
- Configuration files
- Dependencies

As we only got the information that it's "crashing", we cannot guarantee it will work.